# ngrx/strore example app, why child state extends root state?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I'm playing with the example app of ngrx-store https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app and can't figure out a piece of code in "app\auth\reducers\index.ts" file

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  auth: AuthState;
}
```

In the same file we already have interface that describes a state

```
export interface AuthState {
  status: fromAuth.State;
  loginPage: fromLoginPage.State;
}
```

So why we should create another state, and what's more important, why this new state should extend the root state?

Here is the root state

```
export interface State {
  layout: fromLayout.State;
  routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
}
```

Isn't the whole state is just an object that holds all the child states, like auth state, and books state? So it can look like

```
{
  root: rootState,
  auth: authState,
  books: booksState
}
```

Then, when a child state extends the root state, it just adds up more information to the child state, that isn't relevant to it? So in this case `authState` and `booksState` contain the same info that `rootState` contains plus its own information?

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments in `app\reducers\index.ts`:

> As mentioned, we treat each reducer like a table in a database. This means our top level state interface is just a map of keys to inner state types.

In this example, `interface AuthState` describes a state of a feature module.

`interface State extends fromRoot.State` gives you information about full state accessible from this feature module (feature module state + top state). Under the same name, you should keep different information depending on the feature module. It’s a good practice.